# How to get mhddfs to mount drives at boot

Tags: boot, mount, fstab

Ok so I have two drives for general data and two for videos on my server now running 18.04.1, I have all 4 drives mount at boot but when I go to add the line that the tutorial suggested my system won't fully boot rather it just sits on a screen just after the networking has been processed and rather than giving me the option to log in it comes up with root@my-server, if I delete the lines for each drive from fstab then the system boots as normal but I need a way to launching the mhddfs drives at boot, any ideas?

The line is:

```
mhddfs#/mnt/Data1,/mnt/Data2 /mnt/Data fuse defaults,allow_other 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have a `#` sign on the line?

You might put it at the beginning of a comment line, which will be ignored.

```
#mhddfs /mnt/Data1,/mnt/Data2 /mnt/Data fuse defaults,allow_other 0 0
```

Also, it doesn't look like your line is formatted properly.
The first entry should be a drive and not a mount point.

If you want to make things easier, try combining your drives with LVM.

Comment: I have the hash there because it is in the tutorial page here: https://romanrm.net/mhddfs

The way mhddfs works is you first have to mount drives which I have done in fstab they launch at boot with no problems under /Data1 /Data2 /Videos1 /Videos2 they are drives sdb1 sdc1 sdd1 and sde1.

I have not used LVM before, but I will look into it. But I have spent a fair amount of time on this method so I would prefer to stick with it.